# Why does Android's parcel.readList work with ImmutableList?

Tags: java, android, list, parcel, immutablelist

Why is it possible to use an ImmutableList with `parcel.readList`?

```
void someParcelFunction(Parcel parcel) {
    ImmutableList<String> myList = ImmutableList.of();

    parcel.readList(myList, ImmutableList.class.getClassLoader(), String.class);
}
```

When I look at the source code for `parcel.readList` I can see that the `add` method is called on the `outVal` (first argument) of the method:

```
private <T> void readListInternal(@NonNull List<? super T> outVal, int n,
            @Nullable ClassLoader loader, @Nullable Class<T> clazz) {
        while (n > 0) {
            T value = readValue(loader, clazz);
            //Log.d(TAG, "Unmarshalling value=" + value);
            outVal.add(value);
            n--;
        }
    }
```

But in Guava's documentation it looks like this method is deprecated and should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`: https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#add-int-E-. And this would make sense because not only should an Immutable list be immutable, but I am also initialising this list to empty and then it seems like it's actually being modified.

However, the code above runs and no exceptions are thrown. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure the input list is non-empty? It will only attempt to add to the list, and thus be able to throw, if the number of elements `n` is more than 0. Other than that, this looks fundamentally destined to fail, so you need to provide a more complete example, like creation of the Parcel. Could it also be that the code is throwing, but you're catching and swallowing the exception somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. Possibly you are either not running the code you think you are running, or you're attempting to read in a 0-len list, which ends up never calling `add`, thus never causing any problem.

The fact that the method is deprecated is **irrelevant** - that is a compile-time (i.e. 'as you write it', not 'as you run it') only feature that means that invoking `.add` on an expression whose type is `ImmutableList` gets you a warning, but invoking it on an expression whose type is `List` (and an ImmutableList is a kind of list, so, that's possible, and in fact exactly what happens in `readList`'s implementation) causes no issues, and `@deprecated` doesn't do anything else.

The fact that ImmutableList's `add` implementation straight up throws - that would, of course, do something at runtime. In fact, readList cannot possibly get around this. Hence, either you aren't running what you think you are running, or, you're reading a 0-len list, in which case that while loop is skipped immediately, and `outVal.add` is never invoked.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are correct. The function never gets called.